# Hardy-Ramanujan theorem for $\Omega(n)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, analytic-functions

From the Theorem we have that $$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}(\omega(n)-\log\log n)^2=(1+o(1))\log\log x,$$ and for all $\epsilon>0$ $$|\{n\leq x:|\omega(n)-\log\log n|\geq\epsilon\log\log x\}|<<\epsilon x.$$ In every reference I've read It's written that the same results holds for $\Omega(n)$, but for me It's not clear! Do the same estimates of $\omega(n)$ hold for $\Omega(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer for the first estimate is *yes*.  I base my explanation on Problem 26 in Section 8.3 of I. Niven, H. S. Zuckerman, H. L. Montgomery, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991.  In the following, $n$, $k$, $j$, and $i$ are positive integers; $x$ is a real number; and $p$ and $q$ are primes.

\begin{align}
\sum_{n \le x} (\Omega(n) - \omega(n))^2 & = \sum_{n \le x} \left( \sum_{\substack{p^k|n \\ k > 0}} 1 - \sum_{p|n} 1 \right)^2 & \text{(by definition of } \Omega \text{ and } \omega) (1)\\
& = \sum_{n \le x} \left( \sum_{\substack{p^k|n \\ k > 1}} 1 \right)^2\\
& = \sum_{n \le x} \left( \sum_{\substack{p^k|n \\ k > 1}} 1 \right) \left( \sum_{\substack{q^j|n \\ j > 1}} 1 \right) & (2)\\
& = \sum_{n \le x} \sum_{\substack{p^k|n \\ k > 1}} \sum_{\substack{q^j|n \\ j > 1}} 1 & \text{(by the distributive law)}\\
& = \sum_{\substack{p \ne q \\ p^kq^j \le x \\ k > 1, \, j > 1}} \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^kq^j} \right\rfloor + \sum_{\substack{p^k \le x \\ k > 1}} (2k - 3) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^k} \right\rfloor.
\end{align}
The last step might require some explanation:  We grouped the products of two $1$s according to whether $p = q$.  If not, we see from Equation ($2$) that we have $\lfloor x/(p^kq^j) \rfloor 1$s.  Note that I lumped the two indices of summation $p^k \le x, q^j \le x$ into $p^kq^j \le x$ to remove terms for which the floor function returns zero.  If $p = q$, consider Equation ($1$):  If $p^2|n$ and $p^3 \nmid n$, then $(\Omega(n) - \omega(n))^2$ contributes $(2 - 1)^2 = 1^2$ to the sum, and there are $\lfloor x/p^2 \rfloor - \lfloor x/p^3 \rfloor$ such $n$.  Continuing for greater powers of $p$, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{p^k|n \\ k > 1}} (\Omega(n) - \omega(n))^2 & = 1^2 \left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^2} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^3} \right\rfloor\right) + 2^2 \left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^3} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^4} \right\rfloor\right) + \cdots\\
& = 1^2 \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^2} \right\rfloor + (2^2 - 1^2) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^3} \right\rfloor + (3^2 - 2^2) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^4} \right\rfloor + \cdots\\
& \quad + ((i - 1)^2 - (i - 2)^2) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^i} \right\rfloor + \cdots\\
& =\sum_{\substack{p^k \le x \\ k > 1}} (2k - 3) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^k} \right\rfloor \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{(because $(i - 1)^2 - (i - 2)^2 = 2i - 3$).}
\end{align}

Continuing with the original chain of equations, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \le x} (\Omega(n) - \omega(n))^2 & = \sum_{\substack{p \ne q \\ p^kq^j \le x \\ k > 1, \, j > 1}} \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^kq^j} \right\rfloor + \sum_{\substack{p^k \le x \\ k > 1}} (2k - 3) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{p^k} \right\rfloor\\
& = \sum_{\substack{p \ne q \\ p^kq^j \le x \\ k > 1, \, j > 1}} \left( \frac{x}{p^kq^j} + O(1) \right) + \sum_{\substack{p^k \le x \\ k > 1}} (2k - 3) \left( \frac{x}{p^k} + O(1) \right)\\
& = x \left( \sum_{\substack{p \ne q \\ p^kq^j \le x \\ k > 1, \, j > 1}}  \frac{1}{p^kq^j} + \sum_{\substack{p^k \le x \\ k > 1}} \frac{2k - 3}{p^k} \right)\\
& \quad + O\left( \sum_{\substack{p \ne q \\ p^kq^j \le x \\ k > 1, \, j > 1}} \frac{1}{p^kq^j} + \sum_{\substack{p^k \le x \\ k > 1}} \frac{2k - 3}{p^k} \right)\\
& = O(x) + O(1) \qquad \qquad \text{(because the sums converge and so are constants)}\\
& = O(x).
\end{align}
To check the reasonableness of that intermediate result, I fit a line to $f(x) = \sum_{n \le x} (\Omega(n) - \omega(n))^2$ versus $x$ for $x = 1, 2, 3, \, \ldots, 32000$ and got $f(x) \approx 2.2751x - 299.97$ with $R^2 \approx 1$.

Now
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \le x} ((\Omega(n) - \omega(n)) + (\omega(n) - \log \log n)) & = O(\sqrt x) + \sqrt{(1+o(1)) x \log \log x}\\
\sum_{n \le x} (\Omega(n) - \log \log n) & = \sqrt{(1+o(1)) x \log \log x}\\
\sum_{n \le x} (\Omega(n) - \log \log n)^2 & = (1+o(1)) x \log \log x\\
\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \le x} (\Omega(n) - \log \log n)^2 & = (1+o(1)) \log \log x.
\end{align}
That answers the first part of your question.

After I wrote that answer, I found another proof in [Martin Klazar's lecture notes "Introduction to Number Theory,"](http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~klazar/ln_utc.pdf) Section 4.3, which also includes the answer to the second part of your question.